# ruamel.yaml support for both none & null

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I have a YAML file which is as follows

Input:

```
a:
  test: null
  test12:
```

Expected Output: (no change in Input)

```
a:
  test: null
  test12:
```

below is my code

```
import ruamel.yaml


def my_represent_none(self, data):
    return self.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null', u'')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
yaml.default_flow_style = None
yaml.representer.ignore_aliases = lambda *data: True
yaml.representer.add_representer(type(None), my_represent_none)
```

however, this is leading to having `test: null` to be changed to `test:`  this should not happen and there should be no change to the input value.

HOw can I achieve this?

Comment: Your code seems a bit incomplete, it doesn't generate any outut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no change in the input value. Whether the
[Null Language-Independent Type](https://yaml.org/type/null.html) is
represented as `~`, `null`, `Null`, `Null` or as the empty string,
the value is always the same.

The output you want is in a generic way, as you have two values that will be loaded
in Python as `None` and both will normally be represented in the same way. Contrary
to e.g. string scalars, where the information quotes can be preserved by subclassing `str`
**and** have useful instance to work with, you cannot sublass `None` and expect the typical
`if data['a']['test'] is None:` to work as expected. So there is no preservation of the
actual value of the Null-types in YAML, and the output is standardised to one and the
same value.

However if the first Null-type needs to be represented as `null` and the all
others as the empty string (as in your expected output), you can do this:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
a:
  test: null
  test12:
"""

class NullRepresenter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, repr, data):
         ret_val = repr.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null', 
                  u'null' if self.count == 0 else u'')
         self.count += 1
         return ret_val

my_represent_none = NullRepresenter()

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.representer.add_representer(type(None), my_represent_none)

yaml.dump(yaml.load(yaml_str), sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a:
  test: null
  test12:
```

Given that you could, during loading mark the actual representation of all
Null types and store them (with some extra methods of `NullRepresenter`)
and retrieve them during dumping. This will however be non-trivial
if the number or the order of keys/elements with `None` values changes,
or the context changes and e.g. an empty string can no longer be used as representation.

In Python `None` is one and the same object wherever used in your data structure.
To represent that inconsistently doesn't make sense, and is
likely to confuse human interpretation of the YAML document.